# How to solve heat problems Ubuntu (16.04) on MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2010)

Tags: ubuntu, mac, fan, cooling, overheating

I have recently installed Ubunut, latest version (16.04) and am using EFI to boot. Minutes after starting up, the computer heats up to around 70C.

I can't seem to install the `applesmc-dkms`.

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Ubuntu seems to be not cool enough for Mac ;) Please take a [look at this post](https://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/)